# How to set a cookie in webview depends to response in volley that obtain the cookie ? (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, cookies, webview, hybrid-mobile-app

I have an activity in which I get the "Set-cookie" from the headers if the credentials are correct (user and pass) with the post method to validate if they exist on my website and I store them in a SharedPreferences, this works for me correctly but When I try to set the cookie in the webview, it simply does not recognize it, I have tried several methods and still get the webview to load with the user's session.

This is how y

```
params["name"] = User.text.toString()
params["pass"] = Password.text.toString()
        val request = AuthUserClass(Request.Method.POST,url,jsonObject,
                     Response.Listener { response ->
    
                     val headers = response.getJSONObject("headers")
                    val setCookie = headers.getString("Set-Cookie")
    }
```

Now i storage in Shared Preferences

```
val sharedpreferences =getSharedPreferences("Set-Cookie",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                    val edit =sharedpreferences.edit()
                    edit.apply{
                    edit.putString("Set-Cookie",setCookie)

                    }.apply()
                    edit.commit()
```

and finally i try to set the cookie in webview

```
                val cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance()
                cookieManager.acceptCookie()
                val cookieKey= getSharedPreferences("Set-Cookie", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                cookieKey.getString("Set-Cookie","")
                val domain =  urlCookie
                cookieManager.setCookie(domain,"$cookieKey")
                cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(binding.webView,true)
```

I dont know how i do incorrect please help me

Answer (score 0):

What you are setting as cookie in the `cookieManager` is not the cookie value but a String representation of your Shared pPreferences instance.

You should rename your `cookieKey` to `sharedPrefs` for clarity. Then extract the cookie String value and save it into, lets say,  `cookieValue`.

```
val sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Set-Cookie", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val cookieValue: String? = sharedPrefs.getString("Set-Cookie", "")

CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(domain, cookieValue)
```

I explicitly set the variables types for clarity.